# ffmpeg - Skip file if the bitrate is lower than certain amount

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, video-encoding, bitrate, ffprobe

I use ffmpeg to encode some videos I downloaded from various streaming sites to hevc. In windows I use a batch file to convert these files.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -n -i "%%G" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -c:a libopus -b:a 48k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application audio "%%~nG.mkv"
```

Some of these files have very low bitrate and I don't want to touch those. Is there any way in ffmpeg to skip these files? Or any command I can include in the batch file, like using `ffprobe` to get the bitrate and skip it using command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_ffmpeg=F:\2020-SU\Q1569837\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_ffprobe=F:\2020-SU\Q1569837\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe"

for %%# in (*.mp4)do for /f tokens^=2^,6^delims^=^,^  %%i in (
'2^>^&1 "!_ffprobe!" -show_entries stream^=bit_rate "%%~f#" ^| "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /e [0-9].kb/s
')do if %%~j gtr 349 2>&1 ("!_ffmpeg!" -y -i "%%~f#" -hide_banner -v error -stats -c:v libx265 -crf 22 ^
     -c:a libopus -b:a 48k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application audio "%%~n#.mkv" 
     )else set/a "_c+=1+0" && <con: call set "_skp_!_c!=Skipped File: %%~nx# Duration: %%~i Bit Rate: %%~j"
      
echo;& (for /f tokens^=2^delims^=^= %%i in ('set _skp_ 2^>nul')do echo\%%~i) & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal
```

- Output:

```batch-file
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.4+2-73ca1d7be377
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 9.3.1][64 bit] 8bit+10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-3.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(12 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 23 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-22.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=4 deblock sao
frame= 1440 fps= 55 q=29.8 Lsize=    2570kB time=00:01:00.11 bitrate= 350.3kbits/s speed=2.32x
x265 [info]: frame I:      6, Avg QP:22.93  kb/s: 1138.86
x265 [info]: frame P:    705, Avg QP:25.55  kb/s: 498.87
x265 [info]: frame B:    729, Avg QP:28.95  kb/s: 98.52
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.9% UV:0.6%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 58.8% 11.0% 11.4% 6.6% 12.2%

encoded 1440 frames in 25.96s (55.47 fps), 298.86 kb/s, Avg QP:27.26

Skipped File: Live_TV_-_Bloomberg.mp4 Duration: 00:00:36.42 Bit Rate: 315
Skipped File: HVDC Light - ABB 3D.mp4 Duration: 00:03:32.16 Bit Rate: 336
```

**Obs.: 1** There are **two spaces** between **<kbd>^=^,^</kbd>**⟵⟶**<kbd>%%i</kbd>** in:  `delims^=^,^spacespace%%i`

```batch-file
for %%# in (*.mp4)do for /f tokens^=2^,6^delims^=^,^spacespace%%i in (...
```

---

---

**1.** - You home work: Replace the variables below in a way compatible with your scenario, also go to your bat folder:

```batch-file
set "_ffmpeg=F:\2020-SU\Q1569837\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_ffprobe=F:\2020-SU\Q1569837\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe"

cd /d "%~dp0"

rem :: if your *.pm4 files are not in the same directory 
rem :: as your bat file, use the full path to drive/folder 
rem :: Example for drive D: folder/subfolder \Media\MP4\Convert 

cd /d "D:\Midia\MP4\Convet"
```

**2.** This batch is using multiple `for loop`, for it to work you will need to enable `Deleyed Expansion` so that the variables receive the updated/expanded values ​​at run time:

```batch-file
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

**3.** Unfortunately your current `for /f ... dir .mp4 ...` doesn't help much, so replace it with a simple `for` to get all the `.mp4` listed in a loop:

```batch-file
for %%# in (*.mp4)do ....
```

**4.** Use an additional `for /f` to make use of this loop variable (in the `1st/for/var==%%#`) where you got the full path/name (`%%~f#`) of the mp4 file, and pass this loop as input to `ffprobe` already defining (explained on **item 5.**), the tokens and delimiters to be taken in that command.

```batch-file
for /f tokens^=2^,6^delims^=^,^  %%i in (ffmprobe ...  %%~f# ...
```

**5.** The **`ffprobe`** command used in `for /f` loop is:

```batch-file
..\ffprobe.exe -show_entries stream=bit_rate "Google Chrome - Now Everywhere.mp4"
```

**6.** Starting with redirecting `StdErr` to `StdOut` of the `ffprobe` output to be filtered by `findstr` by using the switch `/End of a line` with the **`regex`** numbers (**`[0-9]`**) concatenated with the string `.kb/s` and using proper scaping in **`for`** loop:

```batch-file
2^>^&1 "!_ffprobe!" -show_entries stream^=bit_rate "%%~f#" ^| "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /e [0-9].kb/s
```

**7.** The above expanded command and without the escapes, results in:

```batch-file
2>&1 ..\ffprobe.exe -show_entries stream=bit_rate "Google Chrome - Now Everywhere.mkv" | "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /e [0-9].kb/s
```

**8.** The output of the above command treated by the `findstr` filter results in:

```
Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 350 kb/s
```

**9.** The output of the above command treated by the `findstr` filter results in:

```
Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 350 kb/s
```

**10.** By using multiple delimiters, the strings in **`%%i`** and **`%%j`** output will be **`00:01:00.08`** and **`350`**:
 is for last command output, will be **`00:01:00.08`** and **`350`**:

```batch-file
... for /f tokens^=2^,6^delims^=^,^space %%i in (...
Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 350 kb/s
```

[image]

**11.** Assuming your limit value is **`350`** (*inclusive*) for Bite Rate, you will need to use some `if` option in the work part:

```batch-file
 if %%~j > Bit_Rate      ∕∕ the same:  if %%~j > 349  (349 exclusive) 
 if %%~j ≥ Bit_Rate      ∕∕ the same:  if %%~j ≥ 350  (350 inclusive) 

 set "_bit_rate=349"
 if %%~j > %_bit_rate%   ∕∕ the same:  if %%~j > 349  (349 exclusive) 

 set "_bit_rate=350"
 if %%~j ≥ %_bit_rate%   ∕∕ the same:  if %%~j ≥ 350  (350 inclusive) 


 if LSS - Less Than                if [integer or int(var)]  < [integer or int(var)]
 if GTR - Greater Than             if [integer or int(var)]  > [integer or int(var)]
 if LEQ - Less Than or Equals      if [integer or int(var)]  ≤ [integer or int(var)]
 if GEQ - Greater Than or Equals   if [integer or int(var)]  ≥ [integer or int(var)]
```

**12.** The result of **`if`** is **`true`** or **`false`**, and will perform actions depending on the case, for didactic purposes, we will consider the current file as a **`true`** case:

```batch-file
 if %%~j GTR 349 (
      case true
      ffmpeg transcode file mp4
    ) else (
      case false
      skip this file .mp4
      save the full path name 
    )
```

- ```batch-file
   if %%~j gtr 349 2>&1 ("!_ffmpeg!" -y -i "%%~f#" -hide_banner -v error -stats -c:v libx265 -crf 22 ^
     -c:a libopus -b:a 48k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application audio "%%~n#.mkv"
  ```
- **Obs.:2** The characters: **<kbd>space</kbd>**<kbd>^</kbd>****, are at the end of the line, right at the line break, where in execution, the command interpreter will treat it as a single line, escaping the applied line break.

**13.** For those files with lower bite rates, that is, **`false`** cases in the **`if`** command, you have the actions to save the files that were excluded from the **`ffmpeg`** conversion, and will be listed at the end of the run:

```batch-file
 if %%~j GTR 349 (
      case true
      ffmpeg transcode file mp4
    ) else (
      case false
      skip this file .mp4
      save the full path name
    )
```

- **Obs.:3** The **`if`** also work in differents layouts like:

  ```batch-file
  if %%~j GTR 349 (case true
     ffmpeg transcode file mp4 ) else ( 
      case false 
      skip this file .mp4 
      save the full path name 
  )
  ```

  ```batch-file
  if %%~j GTR 349 (case true && ffmpeg transcode file mp4 ) else (
      case false && skip this file .mp4 && save the full path name )
  ```

  ```batch-file
  if %%~j GTR 349 (case true && ffmpeg transcode file mp4
      )else case false && skip this file .mp4 && save the full path name
  ```

**14.** Using the values ​​in the **`%%~f#`**, **`%%~i`** and **`%%~j`** variables,
where respectively are the path and full name of the current file, its duration and its bit rate, we can easily add a counter (`set/a "_c+=1+0"`) and in execution time we increment to create/define, one by one the information of files excluded from the conversion:

```batch-file
)else set/a "_c+=1+0" && <con: call set "_skp_!_c!=Skipped File: %%~nx# Duration: %%~i Bit Rate: %%~j"

%%~f# == Live_TV_-_Bloomberg.mp4
%%~i  == 00:00:36.42
%%~j  == 315

set "_c+=1+0" && call set "_skp_1=Skipped File: Live_TV_-_Bloomberg.mp4 Duration: 00:00:36.42 Bit Rate: 315"
```

**15.** The set command can also be used for variable and value listings, and using a **`set user`**, all variables with defined **`user+(strings)`** will be listed like this:

```batch-file
>set USER
USERDOMAIN=LAME_SLUG
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=LAME_SLUG
USERNAME=ecker
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\ecker
```

**16.** In the last line, where we have a **`for /f`** loop, it will be used to echo each variable defined with name **`_skip_*`**, which was defined by saving the files that were ignored during execution, and this looping will take everything that comes after the sign of **`=`** (2nd/**`tokens^=2`**):

```batch-file
for /f tokens^=2^delims^=^= ... set _skp_1 .... echo\%%~i
 _skp_1=Skipped File: Live_TV_-_Bloomberg.mp4 Duration: 00:00:36.42 Bit Rate: 315
       ↓
tokens^=2 ⇄ Skipped File: Live_TV_-_Bloomberg.mp4 Duration: 00:00:36.42 Bit Rate: 315
echo;& (for /f tokens^=2^delims^=^= %%i in ('set _skp_')do echo\%%~i)...
```

**17.** The second and last part of the last in the bat file, will let the loop occur (isolated) and only after listing all the files that were skipped, it will pause / indefinite timeout, waiting for some key to be pressed, thus closing / finalizing the setlocal, and ending the execution:

```batch-file
1st part: (for /f .....)
2nd part: %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal 

echo; & (for /f tokens^=2^delims^=^= %%i in ('set _skp_')do echo\%%~i) & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal
```

**18.** To avoid any possible error message (**`Environment variable _skip_ not defined`**), in cases where no file was ignored by `if`, just add **`2^>nul`** in **`'set _skip_*2^>nul'`**, inside the last loop **`for`**:

```batch-file
(for /f tokens^=2^delims^=^= %%i in ('set _skp_ 2^>nul')do echo\%%~i)do...
```

- **Obs.4** Here, the **`echo;`** is only for create one separatist line before to list the skipped files..

---

---

- The same code in conventional/didactic layout:

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_ffmpeg=F:\2020-SU\Q1569837\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_ffprobe=F:\2020-SU\Q1569837\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe"

for %%# in (*.mp4) do (

     for /f "tokens=2,6 delims=, " %%i in ('2^>^&1 "!_ffprobe!" -show_entries stream^=bit_rate "%%~f#" ^| "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /e [0-9].kb/s') do (
         
         if %%~j gtr 3200 (
         
             2>&1 "!_ffmpeg!" -y -i "%%~f#" -hide_banner -v error -stats -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -c:a libopus -b:a 48k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application audio "%%~n#.mkv" 
             
           ) else (
             
             set /a "_c+=1+0"
             set "_skp_!_c!=Skipped File: %%~nx# Duration: %%~i Bit Rate: %%~j"
                 
           )
      )
    
  )

echo.
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('2^>nul set _skp_')do echo\%%~i

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 
endlocal
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[if /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Why does call set work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893287/why-does-call-set-work-differently-in-a-cmd-windows-versus-a-cmd-file)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

  [√] **[Use parentheses/brackets to group expressions in a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)**

Comment: God, you answer is so intensive! thank you for this!